# Trying to create copies of an array using spread operator, but some how the array is being mutated

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread, array-splice

I'm trying to practice with the concept of immutability. I'm using the the `spliceTest` array as my main reference for creating copies of the array and mutating those.  I'm coming to the problem when I declare `removeOneItem` variable, I somehow can't declare a new spread variable using the same reference of `spliceTest`.

```
const removeOneItem = [...spliceTest.splice(0,0), ...spliceTest.splice(1)];
const removeFive = [...spliceTest.splice(0,4), ...spliceTest.splice(5)];
const spreadTest = [...spliceTest];
console.log('removeOneItem:', removeOneItem)
  console.log('spreadTest:', spreadTest, spliceTest)
  console.log('removeFive:', removeFive)

Results::::::::::::
removeOneItem: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
spreadTest: [] []
removeFive: [ 1 ]
```

Comment: Use slice() method. It gives you a clone.

Comment: @EsteBootCamp - you got some great answers (not just mine) - please mark one as the accepted answer to mark this question as answered, for the community...

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> The splice() method **changes** the contents of an array by removing or
>   replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements **in place**.

This means, that the splice operation changes your array

Comment: Just adding up here changing means actual **mutation** of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Immutability of data is a cornerstone of functional programming and in general I'll do what you are trying to do: clone the data and mutate the clone. The following function takes an array and a series of sub-arrays. The sub-arrays consist of `[startIndex, quantity]`. It clones the original array by the spread operator and splices the clone according to the second parameter (`...cutDeep`). It will return an object with the original array and the cloned array. If you wrap everything in a function then your scope protects each return. Note on subsequent turns The second clone (`secondResult.dissected`) is spliced once more and the last log proves the original array is never mutated.

#### Demo

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

const dissect = (array, ...cutDeep) => {
  let clone = [...array];
  for (let [cut, deep] of cutDeep) {
    clone.splice(cut, deep);
  }
  return {
    original: array,
    dissected: clone
  };
}

const firstResult = dissect(data, [2, 3], [5, 2], [9, 1]);

const secondResult = dissect(data, [3, 2], [10, 1]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(firstResult));

console.log(JSON.stringify(secondResult));

console.log(JSON.stringify(dissect(secondResult.dissected, [0, 2], [5, 1])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) when you most likely want to use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

`splice` is used for mutating an array, while `slice` is used to select a sub-array.

```js
const sliceTest = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// select a sub-array starting from index 1 (dropping 0)
const removeOneItem = sliceTest.slice(1);

// select a sub-array starting from index 5 (dropping 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4)
const removeFive = sliceTest.slice(5);

// spread the full array into a new one
const spreadTest = [...sliceTest];

// array log helpers (leave these out in your code)
const toString = array => "[" + array.join(",") + "]";
const log = (name, ...arrays) => console.log(name, ...arrays.map(toString));

log('removeOneItem:', removeOneItem)
log('spreadTest:', spreadTest, sliceTest)
log('removeFive:', removeFive)
```

`slice` already creates a shallow copy of the array, so `[...arr.slice(i)]` is not needed.